# gcc 9.2: spurious -Wuninitialized

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning, lto, gold-linker

I am trying to build our code base with gcc 9.2.0, but when using -flto, I get a dozen warnings with missing information. 
These issues did not arise with gcc6.3.

```
<filename>: In member function ‘__ct_base ’:
<filename2:line>: error:  is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]
```

Unfortunately, the line mentioned is literally empty, and the warning message is missing the identifier which is uninitialized.

I would love to reproduce with a smaller test case but I have no idea which variable it concerns. The two files mentioned don’t mention anything specific. It actually complains about a compiler-generated function (__ct_base).

Is there any way to get more information from gcc on the warning ?

Comment: does it compile without the lto?

Comment: You are probably going to get downvotes if you don't add at least a bit of code context. Ideally code that can be reproduced by others.

Comment: Unless someone has stumbled on exactly this same problem, it's near impossible to assist you. Try and remove parts from the code by trial and error until you remove something that doesn't trigger this. Investigate what that was then.

Comment: also, try clang. It should be pretty trivial to change the compiler to clang.

Comment: @bolov Yes it does build without LTO. I know I can disable LTO, or the warning, to get my build through. But there is clearly an issue there. Either in my code or in gcc (missing identifier in the warning)

Comment: @Peregring-lk the question is more or less “how does one get more context” on a gcc warning. I am building millions of line of code here, and gcc mentions an empty line. I would really like to give more context but that’s what I am actually missing.

Comment: @JulienVivenot Put the compiler into full pedantic mode: `-std=<your-C++-version> -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors`. Maybe it triggers something else that helps you find the issue.

Comment: @bolov I understand your points about disabling lto, changing compilers, removing code. I may have phrased my question the wrong way. This code builds on several platforms, several compilers. I am just trying to upgrade gcc and hit this issue. What I am really asking is whether there’s a way to investigate this further with extra gcc options, for this specific case, in order to start building a reproducible test case for gcc, not how to fix my code.

Comment: this looks like a gcc bug. If you have (and can justify) the time and resources you could try https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/bugs/reghunt.html

Comment: @bolov thanks. I’ll look into this

Comment: I think the easiest way to further investigate this (and get help here) is to reduce your code to a [mre] -- this step is also necessary, if it turns out to be a gcc issue, and you want to file a bug for that. The name `__ct_base` may be partially derived from a class you wrote (e.g., **c**ons**t**ructor of `base`, but I'm just guessing)

Comment: `__ct_base ` is known internally as `base_ctor_identifier` and is related to constructors for derived classes. I can't immediately think of a good way to get more info, except for running the compiler through a debugger... I also encourage you to try and get a small reproducer and file a bug report.

Comment: @MarcGlisse yeah, I was trying to run it through a debugger, since I could easily pinpoint the warning in gcc’s code. But I am now battling with the tons of processes gcc runs when linking this and figuring out which one to attach to. Would be easier if it didn’t take 30 minutes for it to spurt out the warning :-)

Comment: `gcc -wrapper gdb,--args ...` but of course it requires a gcc that has debug symbols, preferably a gcc you compiled yourself with `-g -O0` (and you can source the file `gcc/.gdbinit`), and if you are not used to the gcc internals it can take a while to find out how to get anything useful out of it.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thanks a lot for this. I am sure not used to gcc internals, but hey, one has to start somewhere :-)